# MATLAB: Matrix Index is out of range for deletion

Tags: arrays, matlab, fifo

I have this function where I use an array as a FIFO queue (i.e., put elements in it and process them using a first-in first-served approach). In particular, I call this array a MsgQueue as it holds messages.

The MsgQueue is used when a new msg is sent (event), which triggers the execution of the *handleMsgSent()* method, which I show next

```
function handleMsgSent(this, msg)

        this.MsgQueue = [this.MsgQueue msg];

        while(numel(this.MsgQueue) > 0)
            m = this.MsgQueue(1);
            this.MsgQueue = this.MsgQueue(2:end); % <----- OPTION A


            % DO WHATEVER WITH THE MESSAGE


            %this.MsgQueue(1) = []; % <------ OPTION B
        end            
    end
```

As you can see I have marked the code with **OPTION A** and **OPTION B** comment. So, the point is option B ends up with the "Matrix Index is out of range for deletion" error while option A works (apparently) perfectly fine, with no errors.

Can anyone help me to understand the difference? Well, I understand that option A is not deleting anything but just "discarding" the first element of the array but, why does option B fails in deleting if there is at least one element in MsgQueue?

Answer (score 0):

For an empty array, `end` is `0`. If you check the documentation for the colon operator, for start>end it returns an empty array. Thus, the first option deletes noting in some cases while the second option always indexes the second element.

Comment: I don't know if I understood correctly but the point is that if I enter the while  loop it is because MsgQueue has at least 1 element. So, I should be able to delete the first element of the array, right?

Answer (score 0):

After debugging my code I seem to have realised of the reason. In my code there is a comment:

```
% DO WHATEVER WITH THE MESSAGE
```

The problem was that at this point I was invoking another method that triggered new messages to be sent and thus entering the *handleMsgSent()* method again. Thus, when I modify the MsgQueue before that I have no problems but when I do it afterwards I get into trouble.